# How is $\zeta(0)=-1/2$?

Tags: riemann-zeta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does $1+2+3+\dots = {-1\over 12}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39802/why-does-123-dots-1-over-12)

Fermat's Dream by Kato et al. gives the following:

1. $\zeta(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$  (the standard Zeta function) provided the sum converges.
2. $\zeta(0)=-1/2$

Thus, $1+1+1+...=-1/2$ ?  How can this possibly be true?  I guess I'm under the impression that $\sum 1$ diverges.

Comment: As you say, $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$  *provided the sum converges*. This says nothing directly about the value of $\zeta(s)$ when this sum diverges, for example when $s=0$.

Comment: 1. is true for $\hbox{Re} \;s > 1$ only... 2. you will have to learn about "analytic continuation" to answer this.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39802) and [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8724).

Comment: @Chris, go and try to explain that to well renowned physicists as Lubos Motl that still assert that the sum itself is what evaluates to minus one twelfth

Comment: So, since $\sum 1$ diverges, we take the analytic continuation and then things work out?

Comment: However, i would be happy with that assertion if i would be shown evidence that any analytic continuation of that sum needs to be equal to the Riemann Zeta wherever it is well defined

Comment: [Yet another related question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41938)

Comment: Dear Jason, Regarding analytic continuation in the context of the $\zeta$-function, the answers to this question may be of some help:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/riemann-zeta-function-and-analytic-continuation  Regards,

Comment: This (type of) question was also discussed here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25014/erroneous-numerical-approximations-of-zeta-left-frac12-right/25019#25019

Answer (score 2):

As GEdgar noted, the zeta function is extended to values for which the series diverges via an [analytic continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation).

Comment: Ok this helps, I guess I need to study analytic continuation.